# python "in" operation comparing a string with a tuple of containing only 1 string

Tags: python, tuples

I notice a strange behavior of "in" operation when comparing a string with a tuple containing only 1 string.

```
'monday' in ('not monday')
```

the result is True
as if we were comparing 2 strings

but if I change the expression by adding another element in the tuple.

```
'monday' in ('not monday', 'not monday neither')
```

it returns False as expected.

any idea why?

Comment: The first is not a tuple but a string, it would be if you added a comma after the ending quote.

Comment: Except for the empty tuple `()`, *commas* create tuples. Parentheses simply disambiguate the tuple-comma from other uses of commas (such as in function argument lists).

Comment: Compare `'not monday'.__class__` to `('not monday').__class__` to `('not monday',).__class__`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> 'monday' in ('not monday')
True
>>> 'monday' in ('not monday',)
False
```

A single-element tuple *must* have the trailing comma. Otherwise, it gets interpreted as regular order-of-operations parentheses, which are meaningless in this case So, `'monday' in ('not monday')` is syntatically identical to `'monday' in 'not monday'`.

Comment: The parentheses don't define the tuple; they just delimit what is considered part of the tuple expression. `'monday' in 'not monday',` would create a single-element tuple consisting of the result of the comparison `'monday' in 'not monday'`.

Comment: thank you. but the trailing comma only applied with the tuple right. I tried it with a list and it threw me error.

Comment: @chepner that blew my mind. thanks.

Comment: You can have a trailing comma in a list, e.g. `[1,]` or `[1, 2, 3,]` is perfectly fine.

Comment: guess I was doing something wrong again. what is the benefit of [1, 2, 3,] or even (1, 2, 3,)?

Answer (score 0):

Because the `('not monday')` does not mean tuple, it means string as same as `'not monday'`, if you want to create an only one unit tuple you can write `('not monday',)` (add a `,` to the end).

good luck!